# Replacement and non-matches with 'sub'

Tags: r

Months ago I ended up with a sub statement that originally worked with my input data. It has since stopped working causing me to re-examine my ugly process. I hate to share it but it accomplished several things at once:

```
active$id[grep("CIR",active$description)] <- sub(".*CIR0*(\\d+).*","\\1",active$description[grep("CIR",active$description)],perl=TRUE)
```

This statement created a new id column by finding rows that had an id embedded in the description column. The sub statement would find the number following a "CIR0" and populate the id column iff there was an id within a row's description. I recognize it is inefficient with the embedded grep subsetting either side of the assignment.

Is there a way to have a 'sub' replacement be NA or empty if the pattern does not match? I feel like I'm missing something **very** simple but ask for the community's assistance. Thank you.

Example with the results of creating an id column:

```
| name |  id | description       |
|------+-----+-------------------|
| a    | 343 | Here is CIR00343  |
| b    |     | Didn't have it    |
| c    | 123 | What is CIR0123   |
| d    |     | CIR lacks a digit |
| e    | 452 | CIR452 is next    |
```

Comment: It would be nice if you gave some sample data and output! That way we could verify what you need.

Comment: I convinced myself the question was general enough that sample data might be more confusing but you're right - I've added a short table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling with the same issue a few weeks ago. I ended up using the str_match function from the stringr package. It returns NA if the target string is not found. Just make sure you subset the result correctly. An example:

```
library(stringr)
str = "Little_Red_Riding_Hood"
sub(".*(Little).*","\\1",str) # Returns 'Little'
sub(".*(Big).*","\\1",str) # Returns 'Little_Red_Riding_Hood'
str_match(str,".*(Little).*")[1,2] #Returns 'Little'
str_match(str,".*(Big).*")[1,2] # Returns NA
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the stringr package. Using it I've been able to clean up the process and capture a side case I hadn't anticipated.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you could try using `ifelse()`, i.e.,

```
active$id[grep("CIR",active$description)] <- ifelse(match, replacement, "")
```

where `match` should evaluate to true if there's a match, and `replacement` is what that element would be replaced with in that case. Likewise, if `match` evaluates to false, that element's replaced with an empty string (or `NA` if you prefer).

Comment: Disclaimer: I haven't used the grep/regex functionality in R all that  much, so this might not be the best solution, but I'm just throwing it out there - `ifelse()` has saved my behind in so many situations that I've lost count.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered ifelse() in this case but tried to work out a way to leverage it after your answer. I run into difficulty capturing the pattern from the test without duplicating the process as part of the replacement. I'll give it some more thought.